# Aggregate columns in data.table for descriptive statistics

Tags: r, data.table, aggregate

I am looking at a student data set at the individual student level.

What I want to do is do some descriptive analysis at the faculty degree level.

That is some students are doing two degrees (double degrees eg Bachelor of IT and Bachelor of Science) so some students generate two degrees.

My data looks something like the below. The Faculty assignments (whether FAC1 or FAC2) are arbitrary.

```
  studid    FAC1     FAC2   SUCCESS SEX     AVE_MARK  
    1       IT       ARTS     0     Male    65
    2       SCIENCE           1     Male    35
    3       LAW               0     Male    98
    4       IT       SCIENCE  0     Female  55
    5       COMMERCE IT       0     Female  20
    6       COMMERCE IT       1     Male    80
```

This was generated with

```
students<-data.table(studid=c(1:6) ,FAC1 = c("IT","SCIENCE", "LAW","IT","COMMERCE","COMMERCE"), FAC2 = c("ARTS","","","SCIENCE","IT","IT"), SUCCESS = c(0,1,0,0,0,1), SEX=c("Male","Male","Male","Female","Female","Male"), AVE_MARK=c(65,35,98,55,20,80))
```

How would I go about producing something like this (made up figures) to create a Faculty column that incorporates both FAC1 and FAC2 columns? I have been trying to use the lapply function across FAC1 and FAC2 but keep hitting dead ends (ie students[, lapply(.SD, mean), by=agg.by, .SDcols=c('FAC1', 'FAC2')]

```
  FACULTY    MEAN_SUCCESS    AVE_MARK  
  IT         0.65               65
  SCIENCE    1                  50 
  LAW        0.76               50 
  ARTS       0.55               50 
  COMMERCE   0.40               10
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like what you are looking for.

```
library(reshape2)
DT <- melt(students,measure.vars=c("FAC1","FAC2"),value.name="FACULTY")[nchar(FACULTY)>0]
DT[,list(mean_success=mean(SUCCESS),ave_mark=mean(AVE_MARK)),by=FACULTY]
#     FACULTY mean_success ave_mark
# 1:       IT         0.25       55
# 2:  SCIENCE         0.50       45
# 3:      LAW         0.00       98
# 4: COMMERCE         0.50       50
# 5:     ARTS         0.00       65
```

So this uses the `melt(...)` function in package `reshape2` to collapse the two faculty columns, replicating all the other columns. Unfortunately, this results in some columns with blank faculty, so we have to get rid of those using `[nchar(FACULTY)>0]`. Then it's simple to aggregate based on the (new) `FACULTY` column.

Comment: I am afraid this is not working. I am getting the following error message:Warning message:
In melt.data.table(students, id = c("PERSON_ID", "success", "SEX",  :
  All 'measure.vars are NOT of the SAME type. By order of hierarchy, the molten data value column will be of type 'character'. Therefore all measure variables that are not of type 'character' will be coerced to. Check the DETAILS section of ?melt.data.table for more on coercion.

Comment: I will check out the melt data table though. I thought one solution might be to create a new object where the individual values with a FAC1 value are combined with the individual values that have a FAC2 value, with FAC1 and FAC2 in the same column 'FACULTY'.

Comment: This is probably because you have extra columns in your real data that you did not disclose in your question.

Comment: See my edits above; this might work better in your real dataset.

Comment: yup, that stacked the two and have got the object I need for faculty performance analysis called 'Degrees'. Also understand the melt function now too.